# NextJS props passing as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to dynamically pass props so I can output different photo galleries on different pages. 1 out of the 3 props works, the rest comes out as undefined with a warning that a title element received an array with more than 1 element as children. I am new to NextJS and couldn't find a solution online.

Here's what I have:

A TS file:

```
type PostType = {
  slug: string
  title: string
  date: string
  photoSrc: string
  photoConst: string
  coverImage: string
  ogImage: {
    url: string
  }
}

export default PostType
```

I got this post markdown file here:

```
title: 'Costa Rica'
coverImage: '/assets/work/costa-rica/cover.jpg'
date: '2022-08-11'
photoSrc: '/assets/work/costa-rica/grid/'
photoConst: 'COSTA_RICA'
```

I pass these props to a Component:

```
export default function Post({ post, morePosts, preview }: Props) {
  const router = useRouter()
  if (!router.isFallback && !post?.slug) {
    return <ErrorPage statusCode={404} />
  }
  return (
    <Layout preview={preview}>
      <PostHeader
        title={post.title}
        coverImage={post.coverImage}
        date={post.date}
      />
      <PostBody content={post.content} />
      <PlockGrid title={post.title} photoConst={post.photoConst} photoSrc={post.photoSrc} />
```

Here are the constants that I want to use as a number to loop through my photos:

```
export const FRANCE_PHOTOS = 10
export const COSTA_RICA_PHOTOS = 12
export const SWITZERLAND_PHOTOS = 16
```

Here's the PlockGrid component:

```
import {FRANCE_PHOTOS, COSTA_RICA_PHOTOS, SWITZERLAND_PHOTOS} from '../lib/constants'

type Props = {
    title?: string
    photoSrc?: string
    photoConst?: string
}

const PlockGrid = ({title, photoSrc, photoConst} : Props) => {
    return (
        <Plock gap="2rem">
            {
                [...Array({`${photoConst}_PHOTOS`} - 1)].map((e, i) => {
                    console.log(photoConst)
                    return <img
                        key={i + 1}
                        src={`/assets/work/${photoSrc}/grid/${i + 1}.jpg`}
                        alt={`${title} detail`}
                        className="w-full"
                    />
                })
            }
        </Plock>
    )
}

export default PlockGrid
```

Here, the `` {`${photoConst}_PHOTOS`} `` things is not working properly & also, this path `` src={`/assets/work/${photoSrc}/grid/${i + 1}.jpg`} `` is not working properly. `console.log(photoConst)` logs undefined, just like `console.log(photoSrc)` does. It all works when I put in paths manually without any props:

```
const PlockGrid = ({title, photoSrc, photoConst} : Props) => {
    return (
        <Plock breakpoints={breakpoints} gap="2rem">
            {
                [...Array(COSTA_RICA_PHOTOS - 1)].map((e, i) => {
                    console.log(photoConst)
                    return <img
                        key={i + 1}
                        src={`/assets/work/costa-rica/grid/${i + 1}.jpg`}
                        alt={`${title} detail`}
                        className="w-full"
                    />
                })
            }
        </Plock>
    )
}
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: const: 'COSTA_RICA' ?..ow you just updated :)

Comment: @Rmaxx Yes haha, sorry!

Comment: Can you show how you are passing the props to the `Post` component?

Comment: In this line Array({`${photoConst}_PHOTOS`} - 1), this won't be somehow your FRANCE_PHOTOS - 1 = 9. It will be literal string 'FRANCE_PHOTOS' - 1  which is NaN. I recommed passing actual photo number instead of passing some string and doing some error-prone interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the expression `${photoConst}_PHOTOS` resolves into a string (name of a constant), like `FRANCE_PHOTOS`. From what I see, you actually want a value behind, i.e. `10`.

So you need to convert that constant name into value. A bad idea would be to use `eval`:

```
const FRANCE_PHOTOS = 10;
const COSTA_RICA_PHOTOS = 12;

const photoConst = 'FRNACE';
const x = eval(`${photoConst}_PHOTOS`)
console.log(x)
```

A better idea coudl be to use object with photos, so you can index it easilty:

```
const PHOTOS = {
  FRNACE: 10,
  COSTA_RICA: 12
}

const photoConst = 'FRNACE';
const y = PHOTOS[photoConst]
console.log(y)
```

The point is, putting variable in curly brackets like this: `{variable}` does not necessarily get "value" of the variable in javascript. Usually, it is just a syntax error (but not in string interpolation jsx code, but even there it does something a bit different). So in your case, the illustration of the two "options" above could be:

```
// bad code, dont do this
const PlockGrid = ({title, photoSrc, photoConst} : Props) => {
  ...Array(eval(`${photoConst}_PHOTOS`) - 1)]
}

// better code, uses object with constants instead of plain constants
const PlockGrid = ({title, photoSrc, photoConst} : Props) => {
  ...Array(PHOTOS[photoConst] - 1)]
}
```

Comment: And how will I pass the other countries dynamically? Looks like in this case, I will only be logging France or am I missing something? But indeed, I want the amount and not the string.

Comment: The variable `photoConst` is already dynamic above. You can think of it as of the function parameter, that is passed in

Comment: appended the answer

Comment: Yeah I thought so, but I don't see it. Could you implement it in my code example? I don't see it atm. Aha, I see your edit now!

Comment: In this case, I still get undefined though. I log console.log(PHOTOS[photoConst])

Comment: The photoConst prop is undefined, the problem is still here.

Comment: Of course you need to define PHOTOS. The code above does not fix your code, it just shows the way

Comment: Yes I did. I can get a number in the console.log but it's fixed. Can't seem to warp my mind around this one..

Comment: OMG I looked over this function. I needed to add my props over there as well!
export async function getStaticProps({ params }: Params) {
  const post = getPostBySlug(params.slug, [
    'title',
    'date',
    'slug',
    'content',
    'ogImage',
    'coverImage',
    'photoConst',
    'photoSrc',
  ])
  const content = await markdownToHtml(post.content || '')

  return {
    props: {
      post: {
        ...post,
        content,
      },
    },
  }
}

Comment: So it all works now. Thanks for the help! But my main mistake was adding my new props haha.